# How to fix the distance between images?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=10)

**CODE HTML:**

```
 <ul class="instagram-images">
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_1'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_1').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_2'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_2').'" wrap_margin="10" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <li class="big-news pull-left"><?php echo do_shortcode('[display-posts include_excerpt="false" category="news" image_size="news" wrapper="div" posts_per_page="1" orderby="date"]'); ?></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_3'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_3').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_4'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_4').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_5'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_5').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>

                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_6'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_6').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
                <li class="big-news pull-right rightm"><?php echo do_shortcode('[display-posts include_excerpt="false" offset="1" category="news" image_size="news" wrapper="div" posts_per_page="1" orderby="date"]'); ?></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_7'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_7').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_8'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_8').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>

                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_9'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_9').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_10'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_10').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>

                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_11'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_11').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_12'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_12').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_13'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_13').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('instagram_photo_14'); ?>"><?php echo do_shortcode('[instagram_embedding url="'.ot_get_option('instagram_photo_14').'" s="t"]'); ?></a></li>
            </ul>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.instagram-images li{
  width:18%;
  margin:0 0.8%;
  display:inline-block;
}
.instagram-images li img{
  margin:0.5% 0;
}
```

I put a picture more clearly understand what they want to do.

[image]

Basically I want, wherever not be done symmetrically spaced

If you do not understand exactly what I mean, please tell me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry..dint get you..

Comment: Also, the link that you have given is not working..

Comment: May want to look at [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is because `li` element are **inline** and are treated as text elements, meaning that browsers add gaps between words or inline elements in this case. To remove the gaps, you can set `font-size` to `0`:

```
ul.instagram-images > li {
  font-size: 0;
}

ul.instagram-images > li a{
  font-size: 14px; // restore base font size
}
```

But this is not a reliable solution, since some mobile browsers don't allow `font-size` and set minimum `font-size` to something more than 0.

That's why it's kind of wrong to be using `li` in this case. If you still want to use `li` but not have the gaps you should put `float: left;` on `li`. This may or may not work depending on what kind of `li` layout you're trying to achieve.

Another solution is to remove whitespaces between `</li><li>` tags (notice that I mean whitespaces after closing tag and opening it). Hacks are described here: [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: It's not crossbrowser solution. Brousers may have implementation-specific limits for font-size (it is allowed) and in fact some of them do have it.

Comment: @Qwertiy yes, I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Inline blocks do have spaces between them, if there are spaces in the markup.

So you have to remove spaces. Or you can use other way like `float` or flexbox.

## Write in a raw

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>
</ul>
```

## Or so

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    1
  </li><li>
    2
  </li><li>
    3
  </li>
</ul>
```

## Use comments

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>1</li><!--
--><li>2</li><!--
--><li>3</li>
</ul>
```

## Do not explicitly close li

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1
  <li>2
  <li>3
</ul>
```

PS: From [this answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988) (in Russian).